# Ubuntu there is no free space showing in side the disk

Tags: disk-usage

I am using the ubuntu 22 version and using 256 GB SDD.

In the below image you can see that 13 GB is available on the machine

[[image]

In Gparted you can see it's showing only 237 GB in total size so where is 19(256-237)GB?

Also in Disk Usage Analyzer, it's showing 151 GB only

[image]

While saving any file I got an error that only 3MB of space was left.

Can anyone help me with how to use the remaining spaces?

Comment: Be aware of units, Gparted displays size in `GiB` while Disks uses `GB`. Your calculation is wrong as it does not take the units in count. It's not `(256-237)GB` but `256GB-237GiB`.

Comment: On ext4 I’m pretty sure that by default 5% of the device is reserved for the system to continue to run if you fill the disk. So you would normally expect to have access to 95% of the drive as a user

Comment: Your disk usage image has a message about not being able to scan part of /. I expect the remainder is there. You will probably be able to free some space by clearing the apt cache and any old kernels leftover